# Avoid wordpress jQuery downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

There are tons of `javascript` files in the `wp-includes/js/jquery` folder that are downloading every time my site loads. They are more than 150kb. Why do they load and where do they work? How can I prevent downloading these files to users?

Thanks

Comment: Either they are needed because you have installed something that uses them, or they are not needed and you need to clean up. Both options require anyone that wants to say something about it to know something about your code.

Comment: Is there any tool or method so I can trace where they are acting or calling?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will update itself and its plugins in your site if you use it. JQuery works in the pages of your site if you use WordPress. If you are not sure, don't delete those files. JQuery is a very popular Javascript library, and it should be that big when uncompressed.

Comment: My javascript files are now more than 370kb. Specially on mobile devices, this is heavy.

Comment: Check what plugins you have in WordPress. It's quite possible that it's one of them misbehaving that way. Remove everything potentially untrusted, alpha releases and the like. If you have some other PHP scripts running alongside with WordPress, check these.